# SQL Server Select-Into stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I am trying to write a custom stored procedure to carry out a select into operation. I want to copy a table (or some columns from a table) from one database to another. I am using SQL Server 2012

```
CREATE Procedure select_into
AS
Begin
    @selection varchar(128),
    @newtabname varchar(128)
    @fromtabname varchar(128)

    Select selection,
    INTO table1,
    FROM table2,
    WHERE selection = @selection AND table1 = @newtabname AND table2 =@fromtabname;     
go

    EXEC select_into, Ecode, relational_db.dbo.work, dbo.Work_Data;
```

I get an error message indicating a syntax error near the "." in `relational_db.dbo.work`.

I would appreciate any help in getting this right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this ...

```
CREATE Procedure select_into
@selection   NVARCHAR(128),
@newtabname  NVARCHAR(128),
@fromtabname NVARCHAR(128)
AS
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;
  DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

 SET @sql = N'Select ' + QUOTENAME(@selection) + 
             N' INTO ' + QUOTENAME(@newtabname) +
             N' FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@fromtabname)

   EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql
END
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a missing comma in parameter list and wrong syntax for procedure declaration. It should be::

```
CREATE Procedure select_into
(
    @selection varchar(128),
    @newtabname varchar(128),
    @fromtabname varchar(128)
)
AS
    Begin
```

BUT, in addition your syntax for an `INSERT INTO` contains extra commas and you cannot perform dynamic T-SQL that way.

Can I suggest you first learn TSQL's syntax for SQL Server.